# Filter regions using skimage regionprops and create a mask with filtered components

Tags: python, filtering, scikit-image, masking

I have generated a mask through Otsu's Method and now I have to eliminate certain closed regions from it that do not satisfy area or eccentricity conditions.
I label the mask with `skimage.measure.label` function and then apply `skimage.measure.regionprops` to it to get information about the area and eccentricity of the regions. The code is the following:

```
lab_img = label(mask)
regions = regionprops(lab_img)

for region in regions:
    if (condition):
        # Remove this region

# final_mask = mask (but without the discarded regions)
```

Does anyone know an efficient way to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to get what you want. The critical function is [`map_array`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.map_array), which lets you remap the values in an array based on input and output values, like with a Python dictionary. So you could create a table of properties using [`regionprops_table`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops_table), then use NumPy to filter those columns quickly, and finally, remap using the labels column. Here's an example:

```py
from skimage import measure, util

...

lab_image = measure.label(mask)

# table is a dictionary mapping column names to data columns
# (NumPy arrays)
table = regionprops_table(
    lab_image,
    properties=('label', 'area', 'eccentricity'),
)
condition = (table['area'] > 10) & (table['eccentricity'] < 0.5)

# zero out labels not meeting condition
input_labels = table['label']
output_labels = input_labels * condition

filtered_lab_image = util.map_array(
    lab_image, input_labels, output_labels
)
```